# I need to copy data from one workbook into another. But it is giving some error

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I am unable to copy data. it is giving error at the line "sel.copy". Please help out

Code:

```
    excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    currworkingdirectory = os.getcwd()
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(cwd + "\\test.csv")
    print (workbook)
    excel.Visible = 1
    worksheets = workbook.Worksheets(1)

    # Copy required data from sheet
    sel = worksheets.Range("E:E,H:H,I:I").Select()
    sel.Copy()
```

Comment: What's the error? Please post the traceback

Comment: Error is :AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'Copy'

Comment: Try doing `sel = worksheets.Range("E:E,H:H,I:I")` on one line, `sel.Select()` on another, then `sel.Copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worksheets.Range("E:E,H:H,I:I").Select()` is ***NOT*** Setting sel To `"E:E,H:H,I:I"` it is only Selecting `"E:E,H:H,I:I"`

To fix Change

```
sel = worksheets.Range("E:E,H:H,I:I").Select()
```

To

```
sel = worksheets.Range("E:E,H:H,I:I")
```

In the end you are best to not use a copy paste at all, try just setting `Range("Destination").Value = sel.Value` instead.